# Getting TS error, "Property 'children' does not exist on type 'TPage'"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component like this:

```
type TPage = {
  title: string;
};
const Page = React.memo(({ children, title, ...rest }: TPage) => {
  return (
    <div {...rest}>
      <div>{title}</div>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
});
```

And I use it as,

```
    <Page
      title="Title"
      style={{
        minHeight: "100vh",
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        flexDirection: "column"
      }}
    >
      <div>Some content</div>
    </Page>
```

This throws an error,

```
const Page = React.memo(({ children, title, ...rest }: TPage) => {
                           ^^^^^^^^
Property 'children' does not exist on type 'TPage'
```

I've tried fixing it by changing `TType` to,

```
type TPage = React.PropsWithChildren<{
  title: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>;
```

This fixed the issue with `children`, but it started complaining for the `style` prop, saying

```
Property 'style' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes
  & { title: string; children: ReactNode; } & { children?: ReactNode; }'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

[image: nice-browser-y7vjd]

Comment: Check out this link for recommendations on how to handle `children` and `style`:  https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react/blob/main/README.md#useful-react-prop-type-examples

Answer (score 3):

TS won't check what you're doing with the props (using `title` and `children` then passing the rest to a div) and won't let you use any props that aren't in the type. If you wanted to extend the functionality of the `div` use the `JSX` type in a union with your props.

```
type TPage = JSX.IntrinsicElements["div"] & {
  title: string;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know functional component in react TypeScript should look like this:

```
type TPage = {
  title: string;
};
const Page:FC<TPage> = React.memo(({ children, title, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <div {...rest}>
      <div>{title}</div>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
});
//FunctionalComponent can be also insted of FC
```

Now after you add the FC you should get the children as a prop
better to write this what.
now for you style error it due to missing style prop in the type
write the type like this:

```
 type TPage = {
      title: string;
      style: React.CSSProperties;
    };
```

as you can see the FC get generic type to get to props
think like prop-types in react javascript but it just don't gonna let you run if you pass wrong type to a props instead of pop a console error